# How do I apply code to all files within a folder?

Tags: c, image, directory

I'm relatively new to programming, but created a c script to rotate images and create a copy of them. However, I was hoping to apply it to a large number of files, so I was wondering if there was a way to apply a program / function to all images within a specific folder. Thanks!

Comment: C - is not a script. But you can write a script in your favorite shell scripting language to run a C program taking different files as arguments.

Comment: I would not doing this in C. This is more a matter for shell scripting. What OS are you using?

Comment: For what OS?  This is a platform-specific question, about platform-specific API calls to iterate folders and files.  There are no native C functions to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If the program gets the filenames to process in its command line arguments (the `argv` parameter to `main()`), you can use a wildcard in the command line when you run it:

```
yourprogram /path/to/directory/*
```

The program should simply loop through all the filenames in `argv`.

If it can only process one file at a time, you can use a shell loop:

```bash
for file in /path/to/directory/*
do
    yourprogram "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass wildcards to the executable. The shell would expand the wildcard to all files it matches. Your main program could look like this:

```
int main(argc, char ** argv)
{
    for(int arg=1; arg<argc; arg++)
        doStuffToFile(argv[arg]);
}
```

That is the best solution if you plan to use this quite a lot. If you just need a quick fix you'd be better of with a shell script. This is how it would be done in bash:

```bash
for file in /path/*
do
    [ -e "$file" ] || continue
    program "$file"
done
```